# Xcode: Mac OS X, removing title bar, but keep window buttons

Tags: xcode, webview, title

I've been searching and searching but I haven't had any luck. I'm trying to remove the title bar in a window, which is the easy part. But I want to keep the buttons (close, minimize, resize) in the window. So essentially the whole part of the window could be a web view, with the buttons still in tact. The Rdio app is a great example, and I've attached a picture of it. The whole white area is a webview. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sort of new to xcode. Thank you.

[Screenshot of Rdio before it loads up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFeoL.png)